# AutoCompleteSearch is not working at the time of search any categories in my android app while in browser it is working properly

Tags: android, opencart

i have a responsive website in OpenCart and i have access it in my webview in android,it is working but at the time of searching any categories Auto Search hint is not working in my android app .
while it is working fine in browser auto Search Hint..any solution will be appreciable
Thanks

Comment: did you read tour own question? what kind of answer do you expect to receive? what would you answer if someone asked the question like yours?

Comment: The only answer, that you question deserves is `You did something wrong. If you fix it, it will work as it should`. If you want more specific answer, ask more specific question

Comment: @pskink and Vlad matvienko  i have one opencart website on which auto search working fine in browser while when i call that website in android by using webview as an app auto search functionality not working...... hope you both got clearly now...!!

Comment: ok how would you help me for such a problem: `"my app doesn't work, what should i do? thank you in advance for any solution"` ?

Comment: @VladMatvienko  i have one opencart website on which auto search working fine in browser while when i call that website in android by using webview as an app auto search functionality not working...... hope you got clearly now...!!

Comment: is JavaScript enabled in the WebView? Show the Android code how you load your site into WebView.

Comment: @VladMatvienko webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);.... ya i already enabled this

Comment: please suggest any solution.. i am not able to get solution for auto search at the time of search anything just like as e-commerce website